# @Scripts not rendering in cshtml head @if branch but do render without conditional logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a layout file that has all the scripts rendering bundles just fine. However as a progression toward upgrading the entire app we injected some conditional logic and the bundle in question stopped loading.

Before:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

   @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/corejs")
```

Again the above works and the bundle loads.

Test:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

   @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/corejsv1")
```

The above also works so both bundles are being generated it would seem.

Failure:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">

    @if (Request.Cookies["abcd"] != null)
    {
        var appABCD = bool.Parse(Request.Cookies["abcd"].Value.ToString());

        if (appABCD)
        { Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/corejsV1"); }
        else
        { Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/corejs"); }
    }
    else
    {
        //default is cookie is null
        Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/corejs");
    }
```

The above fails to load the bundle....WHY??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below in your view instead, use `@` and don't use `;` at the end:

```
 if (appABCD)
 { 
    @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/corejsV1") 
 }
 else
 { 
    @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/corejs") 
 }
```

Comment: Oh, that's strange! works for me. Is your condition working? Did you debug which line it falls in?

Comment: It is working...I had tried that but I think I had a typo. Went back and tried again and you are correct. Working.